# Select an array of IDs

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to query an array of IDs and would like to have a result which looks like:

> array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

But what I am getting is

> array(array('id' => 1), array('id' = 2));

The Query what I am using looks like this:

```
  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->select('b.id')
            ->where('b.game = :gID')
            ->setParameter('gID', $game->getId());
  return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

What is the best way to achieve the wanted result. It should also be performant, since this query will load up to half a million IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_map function to map rows to flat array:

```
var_dump(
  array_map(
    function($element) { 
      return $element['id'];
    }, array(array('id' => 1), array('id' => 2))
  )
);
```

result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
}
```

Comment: thanks that what i came up with as solution. Thought maybe I can get it like that directly from doctrine.

Comment: unfortunately, that what you get from db is set of rows (arrays) not set of scalars even if your projection selecting single column.

Comment: He should write custom hydration mode. Please look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible by default Doctrine [hydration modes](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#hydration-modes). Doctrine has possibility to write [Custom Hydration Mode](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes) intended to achieve goals like yours. So, you have to write your custom hydration mode:

```
#app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        ...
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: true
                hydrators:
                    MyHydrator: App\YourBundle\Hydrators\MyHydrator
```

Hydrator:

```
// App\YourBundle\Hydrators\MyHydrator.php
namespace App\YourBundle\Hydrators;
use Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\AbstractHydrator;
use \PDO;

class MyHydrator extends AbstractHydrator
{
    protected function hydrateAllData()
    {
        $result = array();
        $cache  = array();
        foreach($this->_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
            $this->hydrateRowData($row, $cache, $result);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    protected function hydrateRowData(array $row, array &$cache, array &$result)
    {
        if(count($row) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        $result[] = $row['id0'];
    }
}
```

And simply useage:

```
$results = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
    ->createQuery('{yourQuery}')->getResult('MyHydrator');
```

Or, in your entity repository in yours case:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
          ->select('b.id')
          ->where('b.game = :gID')
          ->setParameter('gID', $game->getId());
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult('MyHydrator');
```

More in this [example](https://www.techpunch.co.uk/development/create-custom-doctrine2-hydrator-symfony2).